# How do I embed (and use) a button in a CMFCPropertyGridProperty?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, propertygrid

I notice this API call: [`CMFCPropertyGridProperty::AdjustButtonRect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcpropertygridproperty-class?view=msvc-170#adjustbuttonrect). But how do I add a button to a `CMFCPropertyGridProperty`? I would like to show a custom button on the right and manage clicking the button.

Related question:

[Drawing my own embedded button with CMFCPropertyGridProperty and detecting the button state](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78127577/2287576)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research I found another conversation on CodeProject saying to use [`HasButton()`](https://www.codeproject.com/questions/525589/howpluscreateplusbuttonplusinpluscmfcpropertygridc). If I add this override to my class:

```
BOOL HasButton() const
{
    return TRUE;
}
```

Then it will show `...` on the right, which is at-least a step forward!

Then, I used the code search feature in Visual Studio 2022 and noticed an **undocumented** method (`OnClickButton`)! If I override it:

```
virtual void OnClickButton(CPoint point)
{
    AfxMessageBox(L"Button clicked!");

}
```